# laravel 5.5 - route to folder

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I upload all my `laravel 5.5` app in to my shared server (www.example.com/laravel/) folder. now when I goto `www.example.com/laravel` it will launch my app. but I have 2 route issues:

1. my route in web.php is not working anymore. when I click:

`<a href="{{ url('about') }}">AboutUs</a>`

it will go to `www.example.com/laravel/about`, and the result is understandably `Not Found` because in my `web.php` my route is:

```
Route::get('/about', 'HomeController@about')->name('about');
```

I even change to

```
Route::get('laravel/about', 'HomeController@about')->name('about');
```

and it still not working. How can I resolve this?

2. I still have my `public` folder inside the `/laravel/` folder. To make all the css and js file to link, I have to change from:

to

```
<link href="{{ asset('public/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

to make it to work. Is there away to reconfigure this?

I can hardcode both to make them work. But that will heavily affect my constant develop and update process. I am looking for a way to set it once and no need to change between development and production.

**Update01**
I tried @ben's suggestion and change the `.htaccess` in the `public` folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]


    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteBase /laravel //<-----this is what I add!
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

but nothing seems to work. I am very new to `.htaccess` so I am not sure of what I am doing there. Any more insight?

Comment: Try changing your APP_URL environment setting in `.env` to 'www.example.com/laravel', if you have your routes and config cached, make sure to clear these out too.

Comment: This will not work because laravel is outside the root as root is on public inside laravel.

Comment: @AaronFahey I just tried your way and not working.

Comment: you should change file .htaccess in public folder, the `RewriteBase` to /laravel